# SFTP Issue - Permission denied

Tags: sftp

We are trying to do SFTP files from mainframe to new linux servers. We provided our(mainframe) public key to destination server team, they configured that one. While sending files we are getting the following error:

```
Co:Z SFTP version: 3.1.0 (5.0p1) 2015-05-01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Copyright (C) Dovetailed Technologies, LLC. 2008-2014. All rights reserved.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         debug3: connect_to_server arg=/bin/ssh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
debug3: connect_to_server arg=-oForwardX11 no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              debug3: connect_to_server arg=-oForwardAgent no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            debug3: connect_to_server arg=-oClearAllForwardings yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
debug3: connect_to_server arg=-F/export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/ssh_config                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug3: connect_to_server arg=-v                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         debug3: connect_to_server arg=-obatchmode yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             debug3: connect_to_server arg=3.40.64.86                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   debug3: connect_to_server arg=sftp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        OpenSSH_5.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          debug1: Reading configuration data /export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/ssh_config                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/zos_ssh_config                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
debug3: Seeding PRNG from /usr/lib/ssh/ssh-rand-helper                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
debug1: zsshSmfSetConnSmfStatus: changing SMF status from 0 to 83                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
debug1: Connecting to 3.40.64.86 3.40.64.86¨ port 22.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
debug1: Connection established.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
debug1: cipher_init: none from source OpenSSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug1: cipher_init: none from source OpenSSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug3: zsshGetpw: passwd name=HEATFTP, uid=999999901, gid=1, dir=/export/home/HEATFTP, shell=/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/id_rsa.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
debug3: key_read: missing keytype                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
debug3: key_read: missing keytype                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug1: identity file /export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/id_rsa type 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SecureLink SSH Server (Version 3.3.0.62)                                                                                                                                                                                              
debug1: no match: SecureLink SSH Server (Version 3.3.0.62)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
debug3: RNG is ready, skipping seeding                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffi                                                                                                                                                               
e-hellman-group1-sha1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              debug1: mac_setup_by_id: hmac-md5 from source OpenSSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               debug1: mac_setup_by_id: hmac-md5 from source OpenSSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
debug2: bits set: 474/1024                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/known_hosts                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug3: __catgets: NLS setup complete (1), using message catalog openssh.cat                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                             debug2: bits set: 503/1024                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
debug2: kex_derive_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
debug1: cipher_init: aes128-ctr from source OpenSSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
debug1: cipher_init: aes128-ctr from source OpenSSL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
debug2: key: /export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/id_rsa (1055C980)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
debug3: input_userauth_banner                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
gemft.sftp.gateway                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
debug3: preferred publickey                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
debug3: remaining preferred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
debug1: Offering public key: /export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/id_rsa                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       debug3: send_pubkey_test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
debug3: __catgets: NLS setup complete (1), using message catalog openssh.cat                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
FOTS1373 Permission denied (publickey).                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Ý22.256¨ Connection closed
```

How can we fix this issue? Currently some SFTP is running fine for years, for new configuration we are facing this issue.

Comment: Do you call sftp as some different user? After `su` command?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. We are running cozbatch for sending files from mainframe to unix server.

Comment: server is rejecting your key for some reason. Server logs contains the information with the reason. Get in touch with destination server team to check the issue. From this log it is not clear what is wrong.

Comment: From destination server end, they are getting error message is "Our IP address + connection closed "

Answer (score 1):

Your key is being rejected probably due to wrong file permissions at server side.

```
debug1: Offering public key: /export/home/HEATFTP/.ssh/id_rsa                                                     
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey 
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

.ssh folder **and also $HOME directory**  mustn't be readable by anyone but the owner.

Ask the destination server team about it.

Comment: The folders must not be **writeable** by anyone but owner.